# How to resolve FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified?

Tags: python, date, time, rename

I have asked this question and was provided possible solutions but none of them work. I would really appreciate if someone can provide me the solution to this problem. Thank you so much in advance.

Trying to rename a file in ~/Downloads folder.

Here is the code:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

# adding date-time to the file name
current_timestamp = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
old_name = r"/Downloads/Test.xlsx"
new_name = r"/Downloads/Test_" + current_timestamp + ".xlsx"
os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

Error that I'm having:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/Downloads/Test.xlsx' -> '/Downloads/Test_25-Jan-2023.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working with full path, so I suggest you locate `downloads` location programmatically and use this path

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path

current_timestamp = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
downloads_path = os.path.join(Path.home(), 'Downloads')
old_name = 'Test.xlsx'
new_name = f'Test_{current_timestamp}.xlsx'
os.rename(os.path.join(downloads_path, old_name), os.path.join(downloads_path, new_name))
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, however, I get this error message downloads_path = str(os.path.join(path.home(), 'Downloads'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'home'

Comment: @JoeCastro you have `Path = ' '` somewhere in your code? And it should be `Path`, not `path`.

Comment: yes I do have path in my code that gets the userid of the user everytime they execute the script.

Comment: @JoeCastro Rename the variable, it shadows the library.

Comment: I tried to rename it but this is what i get, AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'path3'. Did you mean: 'path'?

Comment: @JoeCastro copy the code in the answer without changing the names or the letters case in it. It's `os.path.join` and `Path.home()`.

Comment: I copied it and still I have this error: downloads_path = str(os.path.join(Path.home(), 'Downloads'))
NameError: name 'Path' is not defined. Did you mean: 'path'?

Comment: @JoeCastro you need to import it `from pathlib import Path`

Comment: follow up question sorry, with this I can rename the file with the date. How about if I wanted to capture the time as well? Thanks

Comment: @JoeCastro something like `datetime.today().strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')`? `25-Jan-2023 13:24:24`

Comment: adding %H:%M:%S, I got os.rename(os.path.join(downloads_path, old_name), os.path.join(downloads_path, new_name))
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect:

Comment: @JoeCastro replace `:` with `-`, just like in the date.

Comment: wow! Amazing :) I learned so much from you. Thank you again. Cheers!